# What is the name of the green plant with long thick leaves?

Tags: identification, houseplants, plant-care, flowers

Name of this plant that has long thick green leaves and small bell white flower growing from it. [image]

Comment: I’ve found the name. It’s called xiphidium caeruleum. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It likely is [Xiphidium caeruleum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xiphidium), called *[Cola de paloma](https://slflora.blogspot.com/2015/07/cola-de-paloma-dovetail.html)* in English.